# How do I use a function from subr.el?

Tags: require

I found a function in [lisp/subr.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-26/lisp/subr.el) that I would like to use: [`version>=`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-26/lisp/subr.el#L5171-L5179). How do I use it?

`(require 'subr)` does not work: `Required feature ‘subr’ was not provided`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subr.el` is one of the numerous libraries which is pre-loaded.  You do not need to load it; you can simply go ahead and use the functions.

Note that there is no `version>=` -- the function you have referenced is `version<=`

Comment: Is there documentation for `version<=` on the Emacs documentation website?

Comment: You don't need a web site.  `C-h f version<=`

Comment: Yes, I know about `C-h`. I am just wondering if it is documented on the website.

Comment: Again, you're better off reading that manual inside Emacs from `C-h i g (elisp)` -- a quick isearch shows that `version<=` isn't mentioned.  The docstring seems pretty comprehensive to me, though.

Comment: @Flux No, the info manuals are online, but only some important functions, such as, `car` and `defun`, are documented in the info manuals, e.g., the info doc for `car`: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Elements.html#index-car. I created a website for all Emacs's builtin symbols, e.g., https://describe-symbol.vercel.app/?version=27.1&symbol=version%3C%3D is for `version<=`, I also added some code example there.